# Matlab dlmread function: Specify range to consider first 4 columns only

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Assume an input file is in the following format:

```
1,2,3,4,One
5,6,7,8,Two
9,10,11,12,Three
...
41,42,43,44,Eleven
```

The aim is to read in the first 4 columns as a matrix using the **dlmread** function. From the guide (i.e. find URL below), I have managed to get this far:

```
A = dlmread('myfile.txt',',',range)
```

What should the **range** variable be specified to, so as to only consider the first 4 columns?

[Guide: [http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html]](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html%5d)

Comment: Can the dlmread function not be used with files containing non-numeric fields? [Source: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/56971-dlmread-problem-could-not-read-file]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)? It seems it would be easier since using `dlmread` would require you to find the number of rows BEFORE loading the file. One of the examples in the documentation is about skipping columns:

```
fileID = fopen('scan1.dat');
dates = textscan(fileID,'%s %*[^\n]');
fclose(fileID);
```

To adapt this for your problem you could simply do:

```
% //Open the file pointer
fileID = fopen('myfile.txt');
% //textscan uses a formatSpec (see link below)
% //so the above spec says to get a string and then 
% //skip everything up to the newline character
% //So we can adapt this to yours like so:
A = textscan(fileID,'%d,%d,%d,%d, %*[^\n]');
% //Each %d is an integer number, separated by commas
% //and after the first four, ignore the rest of the line. 
fclose(fileID);
```

formatSpec help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec

You may also want to look at the `'CollectOutput'` flag as it would bring all the data into one array. Without this flag set you will get a 1x4 cell array, with each element containing a column of data. With the flag set, `A` will be a one element cell array, with the element being a `4xnrows` array of values.

This also addresses the problem of non-numeric fields since textscan can handle any data and will skip those fields as they fit into the format spec.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is by using readtable, it allows you to import different data types, then with that table you can choose the numeric fields and convert them into an array by using table2array.

Comment: please elaborate your answer-review